# MSBuild: How Do I Calculate a File Checksum Using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

How Do I Calculate a File Checksum Using MSBuild?

I don't want to take a dependency on MSBuild extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use C# code within the project file.
The sample shows how to pass parameter to and from C# code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <UsingTask TaskName="GenerateHash" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <Checksum ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
              using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
              {                
                  using (var stream = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open))
                  {
                      byte[] bytes = md5.ComputeHash(stream);  

                      // Convert byte array to a string   
                      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
                      for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)  
                      {  
                          builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));  
                      }  
                      Checksum = builder.ToString();
                  }
              }
          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="GenerateManifestJson" AfterTargets="PostBuild" >
    <GenerateHash InputFile="$(FileName)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Checksum"
          PropertyName="ArtifactChecksum" />
    </GenerateHash>


    <ItemGroup>
      <ManifestJson Include="{" />
      <ManifestJson Include="%20&quot;checksum&quot;:&quot;$(ArtifactChecksum)&quot;" />
      <ManifestJson Include="}" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <WriteLinesToFile File="c:\temp\hello.manifest.json" Lines="@(ManifestJson)" Overwrite="true" Encoding="utf-8" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been added in MSBuild v16, see [GetFileHash Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/getfilehash-task).

Example:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToHash Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="GetHash">
    <GetFileHash Files="@(FilesToHash)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Items"
          ItemName="FilesWithHashes" />
    </GetFileHash>

    <Message Importance="High"
             Text="@(FilesWithHashes->'%(Identity): %(FileHash)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```